# Song 4 by Mr Physicson

Tags: wordplay, music, science

Years have passed, so the songs mr Physicson sings when at leisurely company with his son are not (neccessarily) nursery songs anymore.

However, he has grown old himself, so cumulatively to his unique way of paraphrasing lyrics, he might have heard the original words just a tad differently, in a literal OR metaphorical way.

This night, there were having a spirited barbeque at night, so he started:

```
A set of 4 friends, having preferences more towards the ionizing side,
went to that place with waters and human rights.
The mission was to dig a polymer surface
while acommodation was restricted to foundations of, again, polymer.
Note that the height of the acceptable light cone was short.

Some seriously skilled scientists were there, including 
a doctor capable of creating life - he had a fancy lighter on hand,
and there were also the best inventors around.
It was really a spacetime to behold!
However, the location was incendiarily attacked by an intelligence quotient-deficient society member,
carrying a portable signal launcher. Resulting in...
(joy intensifies)
combustion products on the surface,
plasma at a height.
```

What did Mr Physicson sing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Smoke on the Water* by Deep Purple

A set of 4 friends, having preferences more towards the ionizing side,

> *We all came out to Montreux*
>  The four members of the music group. It suggests purple is at the high end of the spectrum, though this is a tad inaccurate since purple is a mix of blue and red.

went to that place with waters and human rights.

> *On the Lake Geneva shoreline*
>  A lake in Geneva would be water near the place that gave us the Geneva Convention.

The mission was to dig a polymer surface
while acommodation was restricted to foundations of, again, polymer.

> *To make records with a mobile, yeah*
>  Records were made of polymer. A mobile recording studio would be on rubber tires.

Note that the height of the acceptable light cone was short.

> *We didn't have much time now*
>  A light cone is a thing from the study of relativity, the height being time.

Some seriously skilled scientists were there, including
a doctor capable of creating life - he had a fancy lighter on hand,
and there were also the best inventors around.

> *Frank Zappa and the Mothers*
>  Frank Zappa and the Mothers of Invention, a music group. Frank Zappa being compared to Frankenstein. If they are the mothers of invention they must be the best inventors.

It was really a spacetime to behold!

> *Were at the best place around*
>  The best place would be a spacetime to behold.

However, the location was incendiarily attacked by an intelligence quotient-deficient society member,
carrying a portable signal launcher. Resulting in...

> *But some stupid with a flare gun*
>  *Burned the place to the ground*
>  IQ deficient equals stupid, and the signal launcher is a flare gun.

(joy intensifies)
combustion products on the surface,
plasma at a height.

> *Smoke on the water, a fire in the sky*
>  *(Smoke) on the water, you guys are great*
>  The smoke on the water is on the surface, fire is being compared to plasma.

And lastly here is

> a link to a YouTube vid with [lyrics.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4__vwHL6mAs)

Thank you and good night!